# Login OAuth não funciona em dispositivos móveis

Tags: php, facebook, google, oauth

Criei meu sistema de login OAuth com php que funciona normalmente acessando pelo computador, mas ao testar ele pelo meu celular da erro, ele diz que a minha url não está autorizada tanto no login via facebook quanto ao login pelo google. Lembrando que meu site não tem um subdominio para quando é acessado por um dispositivo móvel, ele usa a mesma url em todos os dispositivos. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema. Não encontrei a solucao em lugar nenhum. Espero que consigam responder aqui.

Comment: Você está a abrir a página de autorização de login em um pop-up ou em uma nova página? Até onde eu sei o Chrome no Android tem problemas para lidar com um popup, por algum motivo que desconheço. Não sei se é o mesmo problema.

Comment: por padrão ele abre a popup no pc, mas no cel parece que abre outra pagina mesmo... imaginei que poderia ser como o meu servidor de hospedagem trata o acesso mobile... talvez ele criasse um subdominio internamente, sei lá, foi a única coisa que imaginei que poderia ser mas também segundo eles isso não acontece. Também baixei o firefox para testar e deu o mesmo problema então o problema não é com o chrome, pedi uma pessoa para testar no IOS e nada também =\. Não sei oq fazer mais

Comment: vinicius se vc encontrar a resposta por favor me mande aqui tb

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei.O Oauth está funcionando, porém, precisava de algumas configurações adicionais. Vá em http://developers.facebook.com/, e defina as configurações de login do seu app da seguinte forma:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O último botão é o que faz com que autorize o login por dispositivos móveis. Altere e salve e funcionará.